# Running the script on POSTMAN its fine but after integration in my app it throws an exception End of input at character 0 of

Tags: php, android, json, android-volley

android code

```
public class Fragment_orders extends Fragment {
    View view;
    TextView dob,amountvalue ;
    EditText Blockno,Street,Pincode;
    Spinner sp;
    int amount;
    Button bt,bookdabba;
    TextView history;

    String blocknob,streetb,pincodeb,spinnerb;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_orders, container, false);

        history = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.previousorders);
        history.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(),Histroy_Activity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });



       //values intialisd
        dob = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.date);
        bt = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.calculate);
        amountvalue = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.amount);
        bookdabba = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.bookdabba);
        Blockno = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.blocknobooking);
        Street = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.streetnobooking);
        Pincode = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.pincodebooking);
        sp =(Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.booking_type);


        spinnerb = sp.getSelectedItem().toString();
        blocknob= Blockno.getText().toString();
        streetb = Street.getText().toString();
        pincodeb = Pincode.getText().toString();

        //date functn
                run();
        //calc amount
        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                amount();
            }
        });
        //booking daabba
        bookdabba.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dabbabook();
            }
        });
        return  view;

    }
    public void run(){
        dob.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                DialogFragment newFragment = new SelectDateFragment();
                newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "DatePicker");

            }
        });
    }
    public void amount(){
        sp =(Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.booking_type);
        String type = sp.getSelectedItem().toString();
        if(type.equals("Weekly")){
             amount = 210;
        }else if (type.equals("Monthly") ){
            amount = 900;
        }else{
            amount = 2700;
        }
        amountvalue.setText("₹ "+String.valueOf(amount));

    }
    public void dabbabook(){

        sp =(Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.booking_type);
        final String type1 = sp.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String bookdabbaURL= "http://35ad9b86.ngrok.io/1/b11.php";
        StringRequest stringRequest  = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, bookdabbaURL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                            String code = jsonObject.getString("message");
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), code, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "connection error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        }){
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("logininfo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            String emailid = sharedPreferences.getString("emailid","");

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("emailid",emailid);

                params.put("date ",String.valueOf(dob));
                params.put("type",type1);
                params.put("amount",String.valueOf(amount));
                params.put("status",spinnerb);
                params.put("blockno",blocknob);
                params.put("streetno",streetb);
                params.put("pincode",pincodeb);

                return params;
            }
        };
        mysingleton.getInstance(getActivity()).addtoRequest(stringRequest);



    }
}
```

php code:

```
<?php
 include_once 'connection.php';
  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  class user{
      private $db;
      private $connection;

      function __construct(){
            $this -> db = new DB_Connection();
            $this -> connection = $this->db->getConnection();   //to connect to database      
      }
    public function Bookdabba($emailid,$date,$type,$amount,$blockno,$streetno,$pincode){
        $allchar="0123456789";
    $allchar1 = str_shuffle($allchar);
    $randomkey = substr($allchar1,0,8);
    $orderid = "BDid-".$randomkey;



    $sql1 = "insert into              bookings(emailid,orderid,date,type,amount,status,blockno,streetno,pincode) values ('$emailid','$orderid','$date','$type','$amount','Active','$blockno','$streetno','$pincode')";
    $inserted = mysqli_query($this -> connection,$sql1);
    $response =array();
          if($inserted == 1){
    $sql1 = "insert into history(emailid,orderid,date,type,amount,status,blockno,streetno,pincode)values('$emailid','$orderid','$date','$type','$amount','Active','$blockno','$streetno','$pincode')";
    $insertedHistory = mysqli_query($this -> connection,$sql1);
    $message = "Voila!! your dabba is been booked";
    array_push($response,array("message"=>$message));
          }else{
              $message = "Try after sometime :( ";
              array_push($response,array("message"=>$message));
          }
          echo json_encode($response);
    }
    }
    $nuser =new  user(); if(isset($_POST['emailid'],$_POST['date'],$_POST['type'],$_POST['amount'],$_POST['blockno'],$_POST['streetno'],$_POST['pincode'])){
    $emailid = $_POST['emailid'];
    $date= $_POST['date'];
    $type = $_POST['type'];
    $amount = $_POST['amount'];
    $status = $_POST['status']; 
    $blockno = $_POST['blockno'];
    $streetno = $_POST['streetno'];
    $pincode = $_POST['pincode'];
    $nuser-> Bookdabba($emailid,$date,$type,$amount,$blockno,$streetno,$pincode);
    }?>
```

While running it on POSTMAN insertion is proper;y made no issues with the connection and has checked all the fileds properly even had gone through many related topics but haven't find solution [image: error pic]

Comment: You're not always sending Java back, even though it's expecting it.

Comment: didn't get you but then what should be done to make it flawless and even i tried it with dummy data the problem is same @Farkie